# Printing two values of one variable under different conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, if-statement, conditional-statements

Please consider the statements below:

`sum_value = fixed_value - current_value`,

where `fixed_value`  is a constant, and `current_value` is a function of `thresholds`;

`thresholds` has two `threshold_level` values: `thresholds = [10, 20]`;

I need to find a rato of `sim_value` corresponding to `threshold_level = 10` to `sim_value` corresponding to `threshold_level = 20`, that is `final_sim_value = sim_value_at_10/sim_value_at_20`.

The code part is

```
thresholds = [10, 20]
fixed_value = 100

for threshold_level in thresholds:
    current_value = 5 - threshold_level
    sim_value = fixed_value - current_value

    def sim_value_multi(threshold_level):
        if threshold_level == 10:
            sim_value_at_10 = sim_value
            return sim_value_at_10
        if threshold_level == 20:
            sim_value_at_20 = sim_value
            return sim_value_at_20 
            
    final_sim_value = sim_value_multi(10)/sim_value_multi(20)
    
    print('sim_value_multi(10) is ', sim_value_multi(10))
    print('sim_value_multi(20) is ', sim_value_multi(20))
    print('final_sim_value is ', final_sim_value)
    
print('--------------------')
final_sim_value = sim_value_multi(10)/sim_value_multi(20)
    
print('sim_value_multi(10) is ', sim_value_multi(10))
print('sim_value_multi(20) is ', sim_value_multi(20))
print('final_sim_value is ', final_sim_value)
```

which gives this output:

```
sim_value_multi(10) is  105
sim_value_multi(20) is  105
final_sim_value is  1.0
sim_value_multi(10) is  115
sim_value_multi(20) is  115
final_sim_value is  1.0
--------------------
sim_value_multi(10) is  115
sim_value_multi(20) is  115
final_sim_value is  1.0
```

Could you please correct me or suggest a proper solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to obtain this result ?

```
thresholds = [10, 20]
fixed_value = 100
current_values = []
for threshold_value in thresholds:
    current_values.append(fixed_value + threshold_value - 5)

print('sim_value_multi(10) is ', current_values[0])
print('sim_value_multi(20) is ', current_values[1])
print('final_sim_value is ', current_values[0]/current_values[1])
```

Output

```
sim_value_multi(10) is  105
sim_value_multi(20) is  115
final_sim_value is  0.9130434782608695
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted to obtain. The solution is completely simple. Thank you very much indeed.